# TypeError:expected string or Unicode, float found?

Tags: python, excel, unicode

This is my code:

```
#--coding:utf-8--

import sys
sys.path.append('D:\\python2.7.11\\xlrd-1.0.0')
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook('file0.xls')
for s in wb.sheets():
 print 'Sheet:',s.name
 for row in range(s.nrows):
     values=[]
     for col in range(s.ncols):
         values.append(s.cell(row,col).value)
     print ','.join(values)
 print
```

this is my result:

```
===================== RESTART: D:\python2.7.11\test_0.py =====================
Sheet: 实验分组
组内序号,姓名,学号,班级,电话,组内分工比例

        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\python2.7.11\test_0.py", line 13, in <module>
        print ','.join(values)
    TypeError: sequence item 3: expected string or Unicode, float found
```

how can I solve the problem? In my file0.xls,the second row is number rather than unicode.

Comment: `','.join(map(str, values))`

Comment: Simply doing this should make your code work. `print ','.join( [str(i) for i in values] )`

Comment: It has another problem:                                Sheet: 实验分组

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python2.7.11\test_0.py", line 12, in <module>
    values.append(str(s.cell(row,col).value))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: `cell.value` can return numbers as floats and ints instead of strings.  My guess is the Chinese strings return as Unicode, so you should coerce the floats to Unicode as well: `print u','.join([unicode(i) for i in values])`.  coercing Unicode strings to byte strings with `str` assumes an `ascii` conversion and is going to fail with Chinese.

Comment: it works! thanks for your patient help!